# How to let background music continue?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, xcode7-beta5

I want to allow a player to use their music in my game, so I want to know how to detect if the player is playing music from his music library so I can let his music continue playing and if not let my music play in the background.

I use this code to play music in my `GameViewController`:

```
let bgMusicURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Squart-GameMusic", withExtension: "wav")!

do {
    Data.GameMusic = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
} catch {
    return print("no music file")
}

Data.GameMusic.numberOfLoops = 1
Data.GameMusic.prepareToPlay()
Data.GameMusic.play()
```

The problem is that when I try to play music from Music Library the sound stops and it lets my app play music instead of the Music Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the music is playing or not in the background like this

```
if MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().playbackState == .Playing {
    print("Music is playing")
} else {
    print("Play your music")
}
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import MediaPlayer
```

And if you want to play the sound simultaneously then use this code to play the sound file

```
func playSound {
    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "myFileName", "mp3", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work for music in background but when i use sound effect in my game the background music get cut i use the same code to play sound effect in my game is there another way to play sound effect while the background music is played ?

Comment: i am not getting you properly

Comment: Do you want to play your music while the app is in background.

Comment: sorry for bad explanation i mean my game is about smashing square when the user touche a square it explode and it play a sound effect for 1 second when that sound is played the background music turn off

Comment: Register a notification on 'AVAudioPlayer' which will trigger when your sound stops. In the target of that notification put             'MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().play()' which will resume the background music.

Comment: does that mean it will play the sound effect and then resume the background music ?

Comment: but is there a way to play them at the same time ?

Comment: i try it but it play the sound effect 1 time and then i doesn't play it any more all i want is to play systemMusicPlayer music and the sound effect at the same time like in any game for example an fps shooter you have the soundtrack and the sound effect of bullets,fire ...

Comment: I get an error 'CFRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed

Comment: Just remove CFRelease(soundURL)

Comment: i got another error Missing return in a function expected to return 'SystemSoundID'